# How can I get the minimum value of multiple columns in contour?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-contour

**Context**: I have a dataset with multiple numeric columns, which I am analysing in Contour. During one step of my analysis I want to find the minimum value of three different columns for every row.

**Question:** Is there an expression function in Contour I can use to get the minimum or maximum value of two or more columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking you can find all available expression functions in the Foundry Contour documentation under the References section.

For this specific case the following two functions can be used:

- `GREATEST`: Returns the maximum value of the list of values/columns. Null values are ignored.
- `LEAST`: Returns the minimum value of the list of values/columns. Null values are ignored.

The usage would look as follows:

```
greatest("numeric_column_1", "numeric_column_2", "numeric_column_3")
```